# How to Zoom Python Turtle Window?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to zoom the turtle window in python, but don't know how to proceed. Is there any feature which I can use to zoom the window ?
Below is the code where I want to apply zoom. I'm also attaching zip file of code in case below code have indentation errors.

```
import random
import tkinter as Tkinter
import threading
import time
import turtle

class GUI():
    def ParsePacket():
        n = random.random()
        latitude= 28+n
        longitude=77+n
        
        data =[latitude,longitude]   #random Latitude and Longitude Generator of New Delhi
        return data

def update():
    while True:
        z = GUI.ParsePacket()
        x=z[0]
        y=z[1]
        print(x,y)
        tracy.goto(x,y)
        tracy.pendown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    START_WIDTH = 700 
    START_HEIGHT = 700 
    frame = Tkinter.Frame(root, width=START_WIDTH, height=START_HEIGHT)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(frame, width=START_WIDTH, height=START_HEIGHT,
                            scrollregion=(0, 0, START_WIDTH, START_HEIGHT))
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.N+Tkinter.S+Tkinter.E+Tkinter.W)
    frame.pack()
    tracy = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas, visible=False)
    tracy.penup()
    tracy.goto(50.126,8.605)
    tracy.showturtle()
    threading.Thread(target=update).start() 
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement a drag feature (or zoom) in a python window application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276229/how-to-implement-a-drag-feature-or-zoom-in-a-python-window-application)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the above question. But [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22275334/1186624).